# How to select next 5 items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3's carousel to implement a thumbnail scroller for results in my page.

I have the following code:

```
<script>
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function() {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length > 0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    } else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img     src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/CCCCCC&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -33%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  33%; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left: -33%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {background-image:none;}
```

The code, which can be seen running [here](http://www.bootply.com/104336)

I would like to be able to have 6 thumbnails displayed at any one time. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Isn't this a CSS question instead of jQuery one?

Comment: Why dont you just increase the width of the parent div?

Comment: This is actually jQuery. The selection happens here: 

[code]next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length > 0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    } else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }[/code]

Increasing div just increases white space